# DiagrammeR paragraphs inside nodes

Tags: r, r-markdown, diagrammer

I would like to know how to wrap a bunch of text inside a node within a specified width.

know I can have a diagram in the form A-->B-->C, but A, B and C for me are almost always paragraphs of 2 - 4 lines. Of course I can make the breaklines manually with 
 which is useful when you have 2 or 3 words but not really to work with paragraphs.

Is there a way to make the label behave like a text area so I can just set a width and then put all the text I want without manually breaking the lines? If yes, is it possible to control also the alignment of the text?

**Edit**: @CALUM Polwart answer did the trick, however changing the direction of the diagram to 'left to right' adding 'rankdir = LR' into the properties of 'graph' result in font size being reduced, increasing the 'fontsize' property doesn't fix it.

```r
T1 <- 'El usuario detecta un problema y empieza a buscar información para entenderlo mejor.'
T2 <- 'Se considera todas las alternativas ofrecidas en el mercado.'
T3 <- 'Se efectúa la elección.'

T1 <- paste(stri_wrap(paste0(T1, "\\l"), width = 50, indent = 0, exdent = 0), collapse="\\l")
T2 <- paste(stri_wrap(paste0(T2, "\\l"), width = 50, indent = 0, exdent = 0), collapse="\\l")
T3 <- paste(stri_wrap(paste0(T3, "\\l"), width = 50, indent = 0, exdent = 0), collapse="\\l")

diagram <- glue("digraph boxes_and_circles {{
    graph[overlap = true, fontsize = 10, rankdir = LR]
    node [shape = box,
          fontname = Helvetica]
    A[label='{T1}'];
    B[label='{T2}'];
    C[label='{T3}'];
    A->B->C
}}
")

DiagrammeR::grViz(diagram)
```

Comment: if you are using graphviz these may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277864/text-wrapping-with-dot-graphviz ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476432/automatic-multiline-labels-in-graphviz especially dot2tex if using static document

Answer (score 2):

OK. This needs a few things:

stringi's stri wrap to split the string
paste(collapse="\n") to join the splits back together

And then for good measure glue to put the string in the diagram

```
require(glue)
require(stringi)
require(diagrammeR)

# Load the long label into an object:
L <- 'A really very long text string label'
LEFT <- paste(
  stri_wrap(
    paste0(
      L,
      "\\l"), 
    width = 20, 
    indent = 0, 
    exdent = 0), 
   collapse="\\l")  # Use \\l to left align. add to end of text too.

CENTRE <- paste(stri_wrap(L, width = 20, indent = 0, exdent = 0), collapse="\n") # Use \n for centres

RIGHT <- paste(stri_wrap(paste0(L,"\\r"), width = 20, indent = 0, exdent = 0), collapse="\\r")  # Use \\r to right align, added to end of text too.

# Insert the string into the diagram in stead of {LEFT} {CENTRE} {RIGHT} 
# Could do similar with paste
diagram <- glue("digraph boxes_and_circles {{
    graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10]
    node [shape = box,
          fontname = Helvetica]
    A[label='{LEFT}']; 
    B[label='{CENTRE}']; 
    C[label='{RIGHT}']; 
    A->B->C
}}
")
DiagrammeR::grViz(diagram)

# Draw the diagram
DiagrammeR::grViz(diagram)
```

**Edited** to add Left, Centred and Right aligned text

Comment: It would be perfect but for one thing, is also possible to control the alignment of the text ? because right now is all centered. Thank you.

Comment: perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103584/graphviz-how-do-i-make-the-text-in-labels-left-aligned

Comment: Thanks user20650. Updating answer now

Comment: @CALUMPolwart It was all good until I changed the direction of the diagram to 'left to right' adding 'rankdir = LR' in the properties of 'graph'. The direction changed but the font size was reduced and changing the 'fontsize' parameter doesn't do anything. I'll edit adding the code.

Comment: graph [overlap = true, fontsize = 10, rankdir ='LR']

Comment: That line works for me - ie. LR in single quotes?

Comment: But it isnt that - it works with both.  Its not the font size reduced? Its the image is bigger?

Comment: @CALUMPolwart sorry for the late response. When I add `rankdir='LR'` the font is reduced and I cannot change it. This is without `rankdir` https://i.imgur.com/5wSpsUE.png and this is with `rankdir` https://i.imgur.com/o25rQVF.png